# Formatting a time stamp

Tags: excel, date, time, split, format

I am trying to convert the timestamp '2018-08-08T00:20:52.522Z'  in to the format of dd-mm-yyyy hour-minute for the purpose of data analysis. In this timestamp, I am unable to remove 'T' from the middle and also unable to remove the last four digits which represents the time zone offset.

I am unable to split or add space to the timestamp. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in, for example, cell A1, use the formula `LEFT(A1,10)` to isolate the date and `RIGHT(LEFT(E2,16),5)`. These will isolate the strings. Then you can use `DATEVALUE` or `TIMEVALUE` to convert the strings into a number which Excel is able to read as a date or time. To do it one formula, use

```
DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10)) + TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,16),5))
```

This formula gives a number that can be either formatted as a date or time.